# A question about the Milvus docker installation port

Tags: docker, installation, port, milvus

I know that when dockers installs Milvus, port `19530` is the Milvus port. I would like to know what port `19121` does and if it can be installed without mapping this port？
The dockers command to install milvus is as follows：

```
   sudo docker run -d --name milvus_gpu_1.0.0 --gpus all \
    -p 19530:19530 \
    -p 19121:19121 \
    -v /home/$USER/milvus/db:/var/lib/milvus/db \
    -v /home/$USER/milvus/conf:/var/lib/milvus/conf \
    -v /home/$USER/milvus/logs:/var/lib/milvus/logs \
    -v /home/$USER/milvus/wal:/var/lib/milvus/wal \
    milvusdb/milvus:1.0.0-gpu-d030521-1ea92e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them seem to be used: https://milvus.io/docs/v0.10.1/milvus_config.md#Section-network

```
Parameter   Description                               Type      Default
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
bind.port   Port that Milvus server monitors.         Integer   19530
http.port   Port that Milvus HTTP server monitors.    Integer   19121
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it should be possible not to map this port, right?

Comment: Hard to say, do you have a good reason for not mapping it?

Comment: I just thought it would be possible to use Milvus without this port during installation

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Because permissions are required to open ports on the cloud

Comment: Well, try to run it without mapping the other port and see if it works.